Porque mysql solo se conecta en Workbench y no en mis demas gestores de bases de datos?
Instale ubuntu server por medio de virtualbox en la cual quiero utilizar el servicio de mysql pero a la hora de conectarme con otros gestores de bases de datos no me permite hacerlo.
comparto capturas de la configuracion:



ya tengo el usuario configurado para conexiones remotas y aun asi solo funciona en workbench.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! solo funciona en workbench dentro de la virtual?

Verifica si el cliente está cargando el driver mysql correcto (usualmente un JDBC), si el server requiere ssl activado para los clientes, que el server tenga los permisos para el usuario desde donde estés intentando acceder root@localhost o  root@192.168.%, que el tipo de autenticación sea standard (no sha256 o sha2_password).
